# Is there a way to calculate total power consumption per 30 minute interval given total consumtion, Start and End time?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

So I have a data frame with charging sessions. Each charging session has a start time, an end time, and the total kwh consumed during the session between start and end time.

Start and end times do overlap for charging sessions than happen on several charging stations at the same time. I need to know the total kwh consumed per each 30 minute interval by ALL charging sessions and stations

```
start.time <- c(
"2020-01-01 02:04:14 GMT", "2020-01-01 13:40:42 GMT", 
"2020-01-01 16:37:10 GMT", "2020-01-01 22:45:54 GMT",
"2020-01-02 12:17:41 GMT","2020-01-02 15:52:12 GMT")

end.time <- c(
"2020-01-01 09:42:50 GMT", "2020-01-01 14:24:48 GMT",
"2020-01-01 16:50:23 GMT","2020-01-02 02:11:46 GMT",
"2020-01-02 15:00:28 GMT","2020-01-02 16:08:50 GMT")

total.kwh <- c(23.493, 2.475, 0.691, 2.418, 9.778, 0.894)
```

Comment: When do your thirty minute intervals start and stop?  On the half hour? At what granularity do you want to calculate power consumption?  The half hour?  The minute? The second?  Can we assume power consumption is uniform during a charging sesion?  So many factors are undefined in your question.  Also, what have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: from 0:00:00 hours of the first date, which start on the 01/01/2019 or whichever is the first day in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is converting from data based on individual charging sessions to data based on calendar time.  Once you've done that, all is trivial.

**Data wrangling**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Your input data
df <- tibble(
  start.time=c(
  "2020-01-01 02:04:14 GMT", "2020-01-01 13:40:42 GMT", 
  "2020-01-01 16:37:10 GMT", "2020-01-01 22:45:54 GMT",
  "2020-01-02 12:17:41 GMT","2020-01-02 15:52:12 GMT"),
  end.time=c(
    "2020-01-01 09:42:50 GMT", "2020-01-01 14:24:48 GMT",
    "2020-01-01 16:50:23 GMT","2020-01-02 02:11:46 GMT",
    "2020-01-02 15:00:28 GMT","2020-01-02 16:08:50 GMT"),
  totalKWH=c(23.493, 2.475, 0.691, 2.418, 9.778, 0.894),
  )
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  start.time              end.time                totalKWH
  <chr>                   <chr>                      <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 02:04:14 GMT 2020-01-01 09:42:50 GMT   23.5  
2 2020-01-01 13:40:42 GMT 2020-01-01 14:24:48 GMT    2.48 
3 2020-01-01 16:37:10 GMT 2020-01-01 16:50:23 GMT    0.691
4 2020-01-01 22:45:54 GMT 2020-01-02 02:11:46 GMT    2.42 
5 2020-01-02 12:17:41 GMT 2020-01-02 15:00:28 GMT    9.78 
6 2020-01-02 15:52:12 GMT 2020-01-02 16:08:50 GMT    0.894
```

Convert from character to datetimes and derive some useful additional variables

```
df <- df %>% 
  # Necessary to get seq to work
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    Session=row_number(),
    StartTime=ymd_hms(start.time),
    EndTime=ymd_hms(end.time),
    Duration=dseconds(StartTime %--% EndTime),
    kwhPerSecond=totalKWH / as.numeric(Duration),
    Time=list(as.list(seq(StartTime, EndTime, dseconds(1))))
  ) %>% 
  select(-start.time, -end.time) %>% 
  # Remove side effects of rowwise
  ungroup()
df
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  totalKWH Session StartTime           EndTime             Duration              kwhPerSecond Time           
     <dbl>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <Duration>                   <dbl> <list>         
1   23.5         1 2020-01-01 02:04:14 2020-01-01 09:42:50 27516s (~7.64 hours)      0.000854 <list [27,517]>
2    2.48        1 2020-01-01 13:40:42 2020-01-01 14:24:48 2646s (~44.1 minutes)     0.000935 <list [2,647]> 
3    0.691       1 2020-01-01 16:37:10 2020-01-01 16:50:23 793s (~13.22 minutes)     0.000871 <list [794]>   
4    2.42        1 2020-01-01 22:45:54 2020-01-02 02:11:46 12352s (~3.43 hours)      0.000196 <list [12,353]>
5    9.78        1 2020-01-02 12:17:41 2020-01-02 15:00:28 9767s (~2.71 hours)       0.00100  <list [9,768]> 
6    0.894       1 2020-01-02 15:52:12 2020-01-02 16:08:50 998s (~16.63 minutes)     0.000896 <list [999]>
```

Convert from one-row-per-session to one-row-per-second

```
df <- df %>% 
  # The two calls to unnest is not a typo
  unnest(Time) %>% 
  unnest(Time) %>% 
  select(Session, Time, kwhPerSecond)
df
# A tibble: 54,078 x 3
   Session Time                kwhPerSecond
     <int> <dttm>                     <dbl>
 1       1 2020-01-01 02:04:14     0.000854
 2       1 2020-01-01 02:04:15     0.000854
 3       1 2020-01-01 02:04:16     0.000854
 4       1 2020-01-01 02:04:17     0.000854
 5       1 2020-01-01 02:04:18     0.000854
 6       1 2020-01-01 02:04:19     0.000854
 7       1 2020-01-01 02:04:20     0.000854
 8       1 2020-01-01 02:04:21     0.000854
 9       1 2020-01-01 02:04:22     0.000854
10       1 2020-01-01 02:04:23     0.000854
# … with 54,068 more rows
```

Make a note of our baseline

```
midnight <- as_date(min(df$Time))
midnight
[1] "2020-01-01"
```

Convert from time of day to half-hour-slot-from-midnight

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Slot=ceiling((midnight %--% Time) /dminutes(30)))
df
# A tibble: 54,078 x 4
   Session Time                kwhPerSecond  Slot
     <int> <dttm>                     <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1 2020-01-01 02:04:14     0.000854     5
 2       1 2020-01-01 02:04:15     0.000854     5
 3       1 2020-01-01 02:04:16     0.000854     5
 4       1 2020-01-01 02:04:17     0.000854     5
 5       1 2020-01-01 02:04:18     0.000854     5
 6       1 2020-01-01 02:04:19     0.000854     5
 7       1 2020-01-01 02:04:20     0.000854     5
 8       1 2020-01-01 02:04:21     0.000854     5
 9       1 2020-01-01 02:04:22     0.000854     5
10       1 2020-01-01 02:04:23     0.000854     5
# … with 54,068 more rows
```

Finally...

**Analysis**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Slot) %>% 
  summarise(
    SlotStart=min(Time),
    TotalPowerConsumption=sum(kwhPerSecond),
    .groups="drop"
  )
# A tibble: 36 x 3
    Slot SlotStart           TotalPowerConsumption
   <dbl> <dttm>                              <dbl>
 1     5 2020-01-01 02:04:14                  1.32
 2     6 2020-01-01 02:30:01                  1.54
 3     7 2020-01-01 03:00:01                  1.54
 4     8 2020-01-01 03:30:01                  1.54
 5     9 2020-01-01 04:00:01                  1.54
 6    10 2020-01-01 04:30:01                  1.54
 7    11 2020-01-01 05:00:01                  1.54
 8    12 2020-01-01 05:30:01                  1.54
 9    13 2020-01-01 06:00:01                  1.54
10    14 2020-01-01 06:30:01                  1.54
# … with 26 more rows
```

A final piece of tidying up would be to ensure that the "start time" of the first slot starts on the half hour.  But I think I've done enough.  You should be able to work that out from here.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(start.time, end.time, total.kwh)

df <- df %>% mutate(kwh.per.30mins = total.kwh*30/as.numeric(difftime(end.time, start.time, units = "mins")))

df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  start.time              end.time                total.kwh kwh.per.30mins
  <chr>                   <chr>                       <dbl>          <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 02:04:14 GMT 2020-01-01 09:42:50 GMT    23.5            1.54 
2 2020-01-01 13:40:42 GMT 2020-01-01 14:24:48 GMT     2.48           1.68 
3 2020-01-01 16:37:10 GMT 2020-01-01 16:50:23 GMT     0.691          1.57 
4 2020-01-01 22:45:54 GMT 2020-01-02 02:11:46 GMT     2.42           0.352
5 2020-01-02 12:17:41 GMT 2020-01-02 15:00:28 GMT     9.78           1.80 
6 2020-01-02 15:52:12 GMT 2020-01-02 16:08:50 GMT     0.894          1.61
```

Comment: no, it does not sum up kwh from all the other sessions that happen elsewhere

Comment: How are the sessions identified? How are the stations identified?