# Calculate Person-Time (ie Days Spent) in Each Quarter for Each Person in a Dataset

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I need to calculate the number of days that each person in a dataset spends within a fiscal quarter. Here's a dataframe with 4 hypothetical people:

```
id <- c('1', '2', '3', '4') 
end_date <- c("2009-05-24", "2002-02-04", "2015-09-23", "2011-12-04") 
start_date  <- c("2004-07-24", "1992-07-04", "2011-03-23", "2001-07-04") 

df <- data.frame(id, start = ymd(start_date), end = ymd(end_date))
```

I can easily calculate their total follow-up per person and overall:

```
> df %>% mutate(fu_time = end - start) 
  id      start        end   fu_time
1  1 2004-07-24 2009-05-24 1765 days
2  2 1992-07-04 2002-02-04 3502 days
3  3 2011-03-23 2015-09-23 1645 days
4  4 2001-07-04 2011-12-04 3805 days

> df %>% mutate(fu_time = end - start) %>% summarize(total = sum(fu_time))
       total
1 10717 days
```

UPDATE: GETTING CLOSER - I think I'm on to something, having weird errors though

I wrote the following function, which could calculate how many days within Q1 a patient spent:

```
q1fun <- function(x,y) { 
  sum(month(seq(x, y, by = "days")) %in% 1:3)
}
```

Basically, it expands the sequence, counts the number of months, then returns that value. So for instance:

```
> q1fun(ymd("2004-07-24"), ymd("2009-05-24"))
[1] 451
```

The problem is that it won't work in mutate! I'm sure I'm doing something wrong; if someone could help with this last step I'll have it!

```
df %>% 
+   mutate(q1 = q1fun(start, end))
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `q1`.
x 'from' must be of length 1
i Input `q1` is `q1fun(start, end)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to calculate total power consumption per 30 minute interval given total consumtion, Start and End time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301755/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-total-power-consumption-per-30-minute-interval-given)

Answer (score 1):

Simply group the data by the quarter of the calendar year:

```
df2<-df %>% mutate(fu_time = end - start, quarter=lubridate::quarter(end_date)) %>%
  group_by(quarter) %>% summarise(fu_time=sum(fu_time))

barplot(df2$quarter,as.numeric(df2$fu_time))
```

Comment: Thank you for posting! That returns the total fu_time per ID by what quarter they ENDED in. What I need is the total time they spent WITHIN each quarter. I know, weird distinction. Trying to calculate person-years within each quarter basically.

Comment: Do you need to add a measure of 'time' to your example?  That is, we know the start and end dates, but what we need is another variable that holds information about the time (say, hours peeling potatoes) for a task.

Comment: I want to calculate the total number of days that someone spends within each fiscal quarter. So ID #1 would spend 1765 days total, that would be divided between quarters differently. Because diagnosis was 2004-07-24, ID1 would spend ~66 days in quarter 3 (ie last 6 days of July plus ~60 days in August and September) then 90 days in quarter 4 of that year. Then ID1 would spend roughly 90 days per quarter in 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, and 2009. Then in 2009 there would be ~90 days in quarter 1 (ie January through March) followed by ~54 days in quarter 2 (ie 30 in April, 24 in May)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out, needed to group rowwise because I don't have a vectorized function.

So here is the final functions and what it looks like when run. Hope this helps someone else out!

```
> # Calculate quarter 1/2/3/4 times
> q1fun <- function(x,y) { 
+   sum(month(seq(x, y, by = "days")) %in% 1:3)
+ }
> q2fun <- function(x,y) { 
+   sum(month(seq(x, y, by = "days")) %in% 4:6)
+ }
> q3fun <- function(x,y) { 
+   sum(month(seq(x, y, by = "days")) %in% 7:9)
+ }
> q4fun <- function(x,y) { 
+   sum(month(seq(x, y, by = "days")) %in% 10:12)
+ }
> 
> df %>% 
+   rowwise %>% 
+   mutate(q1 = q1fun(start, end), 
+          q2 = q2fun(start, end), 
+          q3 = q3fun(start, end), 
+          q4 = q4fun(start,end))
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  id    start      end           q1    q2    q3    q4
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 1     2004-07-24 2009-05-24   451   418   437   460
2 2     1992-07-04 2002-02-04   847   819   917   920
3 3     2011-03-23 2015-09-23   370   455   453   368
4 4     2001-07-04 2011-12-04   902   910  1009   985
```

The end result is a dataframe with how many days each patient spent within each quarter.